# Как создать веб сокет клиент на C#?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, tcp

У меня есть сервер на php и webSocket клиент на js в браузере. Как создать сокет соединения с этим же сервером на C# через протокол tcp? Использую стандартную библиотеку System.Net.WebSockets.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно реализовать webSocket клиент на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068120/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-websocket-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ни разу я не использовал сокеты, решил разобраться и вот что у меня получилось в итоге:

В качестве сервера для отправки возьму [Echo сервер websocket.org](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html).

- И так, основной класс клиента для веб сокетов является `ClientWebSocket`, он у нас `IDisposable`, а значит используем `using`:

  ```
  using var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
  ```

  Я использую c# 8, по этому using у меня в одну строку.
- Дальше смотрим какие есть методы у данного объекта и замечаем, что по сути там всего 3 метода основных (`ConnectAsync()`, `SendAsync()` и `ReceiveAsync()`. Давайте теперь по порядку:

  - `ConnectAsync()` - Подключаемся к указанному серверу, на вход принимает два параметра (`Uri` и `CancellationToken`).

    ```
    await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://echo.websocket.org"), CancellationToken.None);
    ```
  - `SendAsync()` - Отправляет на сервер массив байтов с указанием типа отправленного сообщения. Принимает `ArraySegment<byte>`, `WebSocketMessageType`, `bool` и `CancellationToken`:

    ```
    ArraySegment<byte> arraySegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Привет мир!"));
    await ws.SendAsync(arraySegment, System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    ```
  - `ReceiveAsync()` - Получает от сервера ответ. Принимает `ArraySegment<byte>` в качестве буфера для записи данных, а также `CancellationToken`.

    ```
    ArraySegment<byte> bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, CancellationToken.None);
    var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, result.Count);
    ```

Вот собственно и все, что надо для простейшей работы с веб сокетами на C#.
Из замечаний:

1. `CancellationToken` - я везде использовал заглушку, для примера сойдет, а вот в проекте лучше создайте объект `CancellationTokenSource`, берите из него токен и работайте с ним. Иначе вы вряд-ли правильно завершите задачу.
2. `ReceiveAsync()` - перед получением данных наверно стоит проверить, есть ли вообще соединение. Делается это примерно так:

   ```
   if (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
   {
       //Мы подключились и можем отправлять данные.
   }
   ```

   В интернете видел, что делают `while` цикл, который крутится до бесконечности, пока статус `Open`, тут уже смотрите сами как вам надо.