# Парсинг сайта на котором при входе загрузка

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Мне необходимо спарсить сайт, но когда заходишь на него, появляется загрузка и из-за этого я получаю только сам загрузочный экран сайта. Как это обойти? Может какой нибудь sleep?

Пробовал до и после запроса ставить Thread.Sleep(), ещё пробовал библиотеку AngleSharp, через async метод, но это тоже не помогло.

[image: Вот такой экран загрузки]

Делал на AngleSharp

````
           var address = "https://www.rustreaper.com/";
           var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);
           string text = document.QuerySelector("div").Text();```

И на обычном HttpWebRequest

   var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.rustreaper.com");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36";

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   Thread.Sleep(2000);
   var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   if (receiveStream != null)
   {
       StreamReader readStream;
       if (response.CharacterSet == null)
           readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
       else
           readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
       result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
       readStream.Close();
   }
   response.Close();
}

Но ничего из этого не помогло.
````

Comment: Причин может быть множество. А решения могут быть разными. Может быть и слип. Почему бы не попробовать а потом приходить с вопросом?

Comment: В том то и дело, что я и слипы попробовал и всё что пришло в голову. Но ничего не помогло, поэтому и написал.

Comment: Ну тогда я не вижу в вопросе перечисления что попробовал и какой результат каждого из путей.

Comment: Представьте, что вы подход к совершенно незнакомому человеку на улице, вот прям к первому встречному и говорите "Мне необходимо спарсить сайт, но получаю только загрузочный экран, как быть?". Какова будет его реакция с таким набором данных? Скорей всего он просто пошлет вас в "мягкой форме". Вот, собственно, а как мы должны на это реагировать? Сделайте минимальный пример, покажите сайт, тогда можно будет поговорить, а сейчас, ну не реально это нам решить.

Comment: В любом браузере зайдите на этот сайт и откройте исходный код страницы. Кода там очень мало, данных нет. Потому что они подгружаются javascript'ом. Значит, вам нужно организовать загрузку самостоятельно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/184217 - посмотрите варианты здесь. Обратите внимание на CefSharp и Selenium.

Comment: С оф сайта AngleSharp ссылка ведёт сюда: [AngleSharp and JavaScript](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/839588/AngleSharp-and-JavaScript) - разбирайтесь, как использовать JS

Comment: Alexander, мне не обязательно использовать AngleSharp, мне нужно любым способом спарсить чат на сайте.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще тут AngleSharp, Selenium и прочее, зачем вообще HTML. Научитесь анализировать тот ресурс, с которым вы работаете. На сайте используются соккеты, а значит и все данные там (например, [чат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGBak.png)), достаточно подключиться...

Comment: EvgeniyZ, не подскажите, пожалуйста, как подключится? Я не совсем понимаю просто. Извините, что дёргаю так.

Comment: Если хотите обратиться через ник, то не забывайте про @ (например @xkrystalll). Про клиент соккетов я давненько писать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1069020/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, при подключении и использовании метода ReceiveAsync(), получается код 400.

Comment: @xkrystalll Посмотрите внимательней на оригинал, а именно на заголовки (можете даже почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), только там про простые запросы, а не соккеты, но суть аналогична) и найдите тот, который **требует** сервер. Как найдете, установите его (`ws.Options.SetRequestHeader()` метод). Я вам даже подсказку дам: `Origin`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за помощь, почти докопался до решения. Но после 30 секунд соединение обрывается. Данные всё же приходят, session id и код инициализации сайта (40)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567 вдруг пригодится.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для вашей задачи не нужны парсеры, ведь если мы заглянем в "Средства разработчика" (F12 в браузере), то увидим там следующую картину

[image: Browser data]

Заметили один постоянно выполняющийся запрос? Вот он и содержит в себе все данные, ведь это WebSocket, к которому нам достаточно лишь подключиться и запросить всю необходимую информацию.

---

В C# для таких целей есть специальный класс, зовется `ClientWebSocket`. Я однажды уже давал ответ на подобный вопрос, можно увидеть его [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1069020/220553), сейчас я на его основе постараюсь реализовать клиент именно для указанного сайта, где конечной целью будет чтение сообщений с чата.

И так, приступим:

1. Создадим пустой класс, назовем его к примеру `RUSTreaperClient` и унаследуем от `IDisposable`, ведь мы делаем некую обертку над `ClientWebSocket`, а он должен быть закрыт.
2. Создадим внутри приватное поле `ClientWebSocket` и реализуем метод `Dispose`.

   Получим в итоге следующее:

   ```
   public class RUSTreaperClient : IDisposable
   {
       private readonly ClientWebSocket client = new();
       public void Dispose() => client.Dispose();
   }
   ```
3. Теперь давайте реализуем 3 метода:

   - Соединения:

     ```
     public async Task ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         await client.ConnectAsync(uri, cancellationToken);
     }
     ```
   - Отправки запроса:

     ```
     public Task SendAsync(string message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
         {
             ArraySegment<byte> arraySegment = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
             return client.SendAsync(arraySegment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cancellationToken);
         }

         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }
     ```
   - Чтение ответа:

     ```
     public async Task<string> ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         if (client is { State: WebSocketState.Open })
         {
             ArraySegment<byte> bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
             WebSocketReceiveResult result = await client.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, cancellationToken);
             return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, result.Count);
         }

         return "Closed";
     }
     ```
4. Имея это, давайте попробуем подключиться

   ```
   static async Task Main()
   {
       using var client = new RUSTreaperClient();
       await client.ConnectAsync();
       Console.WriteLine(await client.ReadAsync());
   }
   ```

   Но получаем вдруг ошибку

   > System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: "The server returned status code '400' when status code '101' was expected."

   400 - это Bad Request, то есть нашему запросу не хватает неких данных, обычно это заголовки. Посмотрим опять в браузере на подключение и пытаемся методом подбора подставить заголовок. Находим, что сервер требует обязательно `Origin`, ну так давайте его добавим нашему клиенту в конструкторе класса:

   ```
   public RUSTreaperClient()
   {
       client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Origin", "https://www.rustreaper.com");
   }
   ```

   Пробуем повторно соединится и видим ответ от сервера, который имеет вид

   ```
   0{"sid":"HU29rYgkIM8s1Ss5BmLY","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
   ```

   На вид простой JSON (с мусором), в котором нас интересует `pingInterval`, ведь это значение, в течении которого сервер ждет от нас пинг запрос.
5. Давайте приведем ответ в удобный для нас вид:

   - Создадим класс, я назову его `Session`, пусть содержит id и нужный timeout:

     ```
     public class Session
     {
         [JsonPropertyName("sid")]
         public string Id { get; set; }

         [JsonPropertyName("pingInterval")]
         public int Timeout { get; set; }
     }
     ```
   - Далее допишем метод подключения, пусть дополнительно десериализует первый ответ сервера и заносит это в приватное поле класса:

     ```
     public async Task ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         await client.ConnectAsync(uri, cancellationToken);
         var response = await ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
         session = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Session>(response.Substring(1));
         Console.WriteLine($"Сессия {session.Id}, Ping/Pong раз в {session.Timeout}ms.");
     }
     ```
6. Отлично, получили данные, десериализовали их, осталось дело за малым, а именно начать непрерывное чтение данных, а также Ping запрос отправлять.

   - Чтение данных фоном. Создадим еще одну асинхронную задачу, пусть в цикле бесконечно вызывает метод чтения ответа:

     ```
     private async Task ReadMessages(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
             var message = await ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
             Console.WriteLine(message);
         }
     }
     ```
   - Ping запрос. Цель - отправить сообщение с цифрой `2` раз в N сек, где N - значение с сервера.

     ```
     private async Task PingMessage(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
             await Task.Delay(session.Timeout);
             await SendAsync("2", cancellationToken);
         }
     }
     ```
   - Допишем метод соединения, добавив в конец запуск этих двух задач:

     ```
     var pingMessage = PingMessage(cancellationToken);
     var readMessages = ReadMessages(cancellationToken);

     await Task.WhenAll(new[] { pingMessage, readMessages });
     ```

   На данном этапе, если попытаться подключиться, то мы увидим нечто такое:

   > Сессия -5iYNPHK-NmTzGn_BmMQ, Ping/Pong раз в 25000сек.
   > 40
   > 3
   > 3

   Это означает, что соединение есть, оно стабильно, сервер ждет указаний.
7. Осталось нам подключиться к чату. Для этого сервер просит отправить 2 запроса:

   1. `40/chat` - цифра, это то, что отправляет нам сервер в последующих ответах после инициализации, можно (и наверно нужно) брать от туда, но я лично не стал, ибо она всегда 40. Ну а `chat` - это некая команда инициализации.
   2. `42/chat,12["join",["english","russian"]]` - `42` - эта цифра всегда больше цифры "инициализации" на 2, `12` - это скажем так "вкладка чата" (начинается с `0`),  `join` - команда подключения, ну а языки - это вроде как какие языки слушать.

   Стоит учесть тот факт, что между первой и 2-й командой сервер ожидает задержу.
   В итоге у нас получается новая задача:

   ```
   private async Task JoinToChat(string[] languages, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
   {
       var data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new object[] { "join", languages });
       await SendAsync("40/chat", cancellationToken);
       await Task.Delay(1000);
       await SendAsync($"42/chat,0{data}");
   }
   ```

   Я как видите, не стал тут мудрить, делать каналы и ожидать ответа от сервера (задержка), это оставлю на вас. Не забываем вызвать этот `Task` в том же методе подключения

   ```
   await JoinToChat(new[] { "english", "russian" }, cancellationToken);
   ```

Собственно, вот и все, сервер нам успешно отдает данные чата. Если нужна еще информация, то отправляем ему аналогичные запросы (например `40/general`). Весь код получается следующий:

```
public class Session
{
    [JsonPropertyName("sid")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("pingInterval")]
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
}

public class RUSTreaperClient : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Uri uri = new Uri("wss://www.rustreaper.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket");
    private readonly ClientWebSocket client = new();
    private Session session;

    public RUSTreaperClient()
    {
        client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Origin", "https://www.rustreaper.com");
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync(uri, cancellationToken);
        var response = await ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
        session = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Session>(response.Substring(1));
        Console.WriteLine($"Сессия {session.Id}, Ping/Pong раз в {session.Timeout}сек.");

        await JoinToChat(new[] { "english", "russian" }, cancellationToken);


        var pingMessage = PingMessage(cancellationToken);
        var readMessages = ReadMessages(cancellationToken);

        await Task.WhenAll(new[] { pingMessage, readMessages });
    }

    public Task SendAsync(string message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> arraySegment = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
            return client.SendAsync(arraySegment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cancellationToken);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task<string> ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (client is { State: WebSocketState.Open })
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await client.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, cancellationToken);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, result.Count);
        }

        return "Closed";
    }

    private async Task ReadMessages(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var message = await ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }

    private async Task PingMessage(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(session.Timeout);
            await SendAsync("2", cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task JoinToChat(string[] languages, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new object[] { "join", languages });
        await SendAsync("40/chat", cancellationToken);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        await SendAsync($"42/chat,0{data}");
    }

    public void Dispose() => client.Dispose();
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        using var client = new RUSTreaperClient();
        await client.ConnectAsync();
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: Result]

Что поправить:

- Как я уже писал ранее, первое число 40, приходит ответом от сервера, стоит его также как и интервал взять и использовать.
- Ответ от сервера может быть в разы больше, чем указанный буфер в размере `1024`.
- Если соединение закрывается, то идет спам в консоль (стоит дописать в условие циклов есть ли соединение или нет).
- Ping/Pong - не уверен, что всегда 2 и 3, стоит проверить и сделать проверку ответа от сервера.
- Полученные JSON значения десериализировать в классы. Но там правда каша, сервер присылает `object[]`, что не есть хорошо, ибо придется писать конвертор.
- Метод `ConnectAsync` выполняет не свои обязанности, стоит вынести инициализацию и прочее в другие методы.
- В некоторые асинхронные методы не закинул `CancellationToken` (например в `Task.Delay`.
- Ну и другие мелочи... Оставлю все это для вас)

Comment: Какой обстоятельный ответ. Прямо приятно читать )

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо, Евгений!